# USB turned RAW when making a bootable USB drive failed and now cannot be formatted

Tags: filesystems, restore, usb-drive, bootable

I was making a bootable usb drive(8GB) for Win7 using the tool on the microsoft site but the process failed. When i tried to run the process again the windows tool told me that the usb is used by another program and cannot be used. I tried **diskpart => clean** on the USB but it failed with a write-protected drive error but when I used the diskpart command to check the USB's attributes it was NOT write protected. Under Computer **Management => Storage** the drive appears to be healthy because it says no problems (primary partition). When I try to format through **Computer Management => Storage** it fails and tells me the formatting was unsuccessful.I tried many other tools but I can't get the drive working. I don't care about the data on the USB i just want it working again so I can reinstall windows.

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, and thus is offtopic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You just messed up with your USB drive while making it bootable, you can try **EASEUS Partition Master** for formating your USB drive. This is really nice tool to make your USB alive back. The second thing is in order to make your USB drive bootable you can make use of **Y.U.M.I** tool to make your USB drive bootable, without formating it.

Also if you are familiar with Linux (Ubuntu) you can try this command to format it:

```
sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdc
```

Here /dev/sdc is your USB device detected by Linux it could be /dev/sdb , in order to make sure you can try it with this command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This will list you all the devices connected to Linux machine.